# Ballot counting nested loop confusion

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement, nested-loops

Question:
Suppose a new member of the city council has to be chosen from three candidates and suppose there are 4 voting stations. We need a C++ program that will count the votes for every candidate and display the result. At every voting station the voters vote by choosing A, B or C on a ballot paper. The voting officer must enter the votes into the program so that they can be counted. X is entered when all the votes at a specific voting station have been entered.

-Use a for loop from 1 to the number of voting stations.

-Inside the for loop is a while loop prompting the user who they want to vote for.

-Inside the while loop is a switch statement to increment the total and default to count spoilt votes.

-The while loop is exited when an X is entered for the choice.

-When the for loop is exited, the three totals and number of spoilt votes are displayed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int VOTING_STATIONS = 4;
    int votesForA = 0, votesForB = 0, votesForC = 0, spoiltVotes = 0;
    char vote;
    int  numVotes;


    for (int i = 0; i <= VOTING_STATIONS; i++)
    {
        numVotes = 0;

        while (vote != 'X')
        {

            cout << "Which candidate do you want to choose?:" << endl;
            cin >>vote;


            switch(vote)
            {
                case 'A':
                votesForA++;
                break;
                case 'B':
                votesForB++;
                break;
                case 'C':
                votesForC++;
                break;
                case 'X':
                break;
                default:
                spoiltVotes++;
                break;

             }
         }
    }

    // display results
    cout << "Total candidate A: " << votesForA << endl;
    cout << "Total candidate B: " << votesForB << endl;
    cout << "Total candidate C: " << votesForC << endl;
    cout << "Total spoilt votes: " << spoiltVotes << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the end im just completly lost with this program and i dont know what to do anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your switch statement is probably wrong. `case` should end with `break;` to prevent fall through

Comment: where is the "for loop from 1 to the number of voting stations." and what are  those nested `for` loops for ?

Comment: `vote` is uninitialized for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, then you mainly need to replace the nested for loops with the loop over the stations and clean up the switch a little:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // initialise totals
    const int NR_VOTING_STATIONS = 4;
    int votesForA = 0, votesForB = 0, votesForC = 0, spoiltVotes = 0;

    char votes[] = { "ABCXAXBXBX" };
    int  numVotes = -1;

    // loop over the voting stations
    for( int i = 0; i < NR_VOTING_STATIONS; ++i)
    {
        char vote = 0;

        while( vote != 'X' )
        {
            cout << "Which candidate do you want to choose: ";
            vote = votes[++numVotes];
            std::cout << vote << std::endl;

            switch (vote)
            {
            case 'A':
                ++votesForA; 
                break;
            case 'B':
                ++votesForB;
                break;
            case 'C':
                ++votesForC;
                break;
            case 'X':
                break;
            default:
                ++spoiltVotes;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // display results
    cout << "Total candidate A: " << votesForA << endl;
    cout << "Total candidate B: " << votesForB << endl;
    cout << "Total candidate C: " << votesForC << endl;
    cout << "Total spoilt votes: " << spoiltVotes << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1231aedbf8bc4ad7)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the help, im juggling my code around for now but in your code i dont understand why there is a int numVotes = -1? how does this affect the program? After looking at your code and adjusting mine, it now seems to run forever even after submitting an 'X' which should end the loop for each voting station and then display the results of the ballet?

Comment: That's just so that the code runs without user input. `vote = votes[ ++numVotes ]` increments and then acceses the fake user input in `votes`. So it reads `votes[0]`, `votes[1]`, until four `X` have been read.

Comment: I'm a bit closer now with this. At the moment it runs perfectly but it stops everytime an 'X' is entered, how do i make it so it reads four 'X's before stopping. I have updated my code to what it is currently in an almost working state.

Comment: Thats because you removed the `char vote = 0;` that's present in my code. Otherwise `vote` will stay `'X'` and all the following ballot stations are skipped because `while( vote != 'X' )` is still true.

Comment: You shouldn't change your question that drastically. You should only append. Otherwise comments will make no sense.

Comment: Perfect! Works just how its supposed to. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).